# print Ajax response is defined but when attempting to print in div is undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm working with a form. When user clicks on button, ajax sends the value, then controller loads model and query database to return one or some registries.

However when Returning, I am getting a response but it seems it is getting all data from table instead of doing a where clause..
Also I am not able to put this result in a div

```
--model

function get($where=array()) {
   $q = $this->db->get_where('tbl_name',$where);
   $result = $q->result_array();
   return $result;
}

-- controller

function get_em()
{   
  $key = $this->input->post('key');
  $this->load->model('model');
  $data['result'] = $this->model->get_em( array('id_guy' => $key)) ;
  header('Content-type: text/plain'); 
  echo json_encode($data);
}


--jquery
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#btn').click(function(){
   var key = $("#key").val();     
   var postData = {
    'key' : key
   };
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/controller/get_em",
    //data: postData , 
    dataType:"json",
    data: postData,
    success: function(response) {
            $.each(response, function(index,item){
              $("#wrapper_succes").append('<div><b>' + index[0] + '</b></div><hr />');
            });
        }
    });
    });
});
```

How to print result in div result of selecting fields from database based on some criteria as they are return with `$query->result_array()` so in controller I understand that  `$data['result'] = $this->model->` stores in  **result** so in php I would only loop in **$result**... but how to do this with ajax, I am not able to print any resuLT, I only get **undefined** or [Object Object] stuff
and when debugging with firebug I can see that response looks like:

```
{"result":[{"id_guy":"1","name":"joe",....,"last":"last man"}, ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your response look like `{"result":[{"id_guy":"1","name":"joe",....,"last":"last man"}]}`.

Then you have :

- an `Object` with an attribute "result" containing an `Array`
- This array contains objects with properties you would like to display

Using directly `$.each` on response will loop only once with values :

```
index = result;
item = [{"id_guy":"1","name":"joe",....,"last":"last man"}]
```

Note that since item contains an `object` you'll have `[object Object]` if you try to convert it to a `String`

That mean you'll have to go through `result`, loop on the `array` and then loop on the `object` attributes.

Giving something like that ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8bAL/1/)):

```
    $.each(response.result, function(index,item){
        $.each(item, function(index,item){
           $("body").append(index + " " + item + " ; ");
        });
        $("body").append("<BR>");
    });
```